# How can I use Jest to spy on a method call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I recently wanted to test that some custom method gets conditionally called in the `componentDidMount` method of a React component.

```
componentDidMount() {
  if (this.props.initOpen) {
    this.methodName();
  }
}
```

I'm using Jest as my testing framework, which includes `jest.fn()` for mocks/spies.  I've read that this would be fairly trivial to test with Sinon, by doing something like the following:

```
sinon.spy(Component.prototype, "methodName");
const wrapper = mount(<Component {...props} />);
expect(wrapper.instance().methodName).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

I'm trying to recreate this with Jest like so:

```
Component.prototype.methodName = jest.fn();
const wrapper = mount(<Component {...props} />);
expect(wrapper.instance().methodName).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

This code fails and throws the following error:

```
jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy.
Received:
  function: [Function bound mockConstructor]
```

Is it possible to test this functionality with Jest? And if so, how?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

The key is using jests `spyOn` method on the object's `prototype`. It should be like this:

```js
const spy = jest.spyOn(Component.prototype, 'methodName');
const wrapper = mount(<Component {...props} />);
wrapper.instance().methodName();
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

As found here e.g.: [Test if function is called react and enzyme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40393486/test-if-function-is-called-react-and-enzyme)

**Please note** *it is also best practice to clear the spied function after each test run*

```js
let spy

afterEach(() => {
  spy.mockClear()
})
```

https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestclearallmocks

Comment: Thank you!  Looks like that just came out in 19.0.0, just a couple months ago.  Can't believe I skipped it over in documentation.

Comment: Will it actually call the `methodName()` function in the Component or it's just faking it ?

Comment: From the documentation: "Note: By default, jest.spyOn also calls the spied method." https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestspyonobject-methodname

Comment: What if the `<Component {...props} />` wrapped around with a `<Provider>`, will this work then ? I'm getting a `Cannot read property '_isMockFunction' of undefined'`. Not sure it's because of the above reason though.

Comment: To me it seems like you are spying on a method that does not exist and that is why you get the `Cannot read property '_isMockFunction' of undefined'`.

Comment: I have the same example with the component wrapped inside a provider and I get the same behavior as @prime. If I try to log the prototype of the component before spying on its members and mounting it it seems to be an empty object.

Comment: @prime Hi, do you know maybe after that time how to work with that? I have same isue now.

Comment: @Vee6 Do you know now how to solve that problem? I am using wrapper = mount(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>); and I get same error.

Comment: @Edenwave I think I did not. anyway what is your requirement ?

Comment: @prime I am describing it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47532213/jestenzyme-cannot-read-property-ismockfunction-of-undefined-simulate-keydo

Comment: @Edenwave no luck, I just refactored my code so that it is testable without using that kind of assertion.

Comment: In case you have other tests you may want to do the following one liner check in your afterEach: ```spy && spy.mockClear && spy.mockClear()```

Comment: Thanks! I see the order of spy declaration is very important. It has to be made before object construction!

Answer (score 23):

I know its a bit late, but I came across this and would suggest that to test `componentDidMount` initiates the call to your nested method that your test should look something like:

**Module**

```
componentDidMount() {
  if (this.props.initOpen) {
    this.methodName();
  }
}
```

**Test - Good**

```
it('should call methodName during componentDidMount', () => {
    const methodNameFake = jest.spyOn(MyComponent.prototype, 'methodName');
    const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent {...props} />);
    expect(methodNameFake).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

If you call `componentDidMount` then the assertion that `methodName` was called via `componentDidMount` is more valid.

**Test - Bad**

```
it('should call methodName during componentDidMount', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(Component.prototype, 'methodName');
    const wrapper = mount(<Component {...props} />);
    wrapper.instance().methodName();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
}
```

By writing the test like this - you call the method and then assert that it was called. Which of course it will have given you just called it.

Comment: Neither of these tests work for me, can't get it to pass at all

Comment: Are you passing all the props that your component requires?

Comment: Finally got it working, needed to create an instance for it and forceUpdate on my spy.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to test `public` methods being called on `componentDidMount` (if you're using TypeScript), you'll need to explicitly call the `instance`'s `componentDidMount` method call, since the public methods aren't defined until after the component is instantiated.

To test something like this:

**Code**

```
public componentDidMount() {
  if (this.props.initOpen) {
    this.methodName();
  }
}

public methodName = () => {
  // some code here
}
```

**Test**

```
it('should call methodName during componentDidMount', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent {...props} />);
  const instance = wrapper.instance();
  jest.spyOn(instance, 'methodName')
  expect(instance.methodName).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const toastMethodSpy = jest.spyOn(sharedMockedOTPComponent, 'toast')
sharedMockedOTPComponent.handleResendOtpFailure(networkError)

//hide loader
expect(sharedMockedOTPComponent.state.showLoader).toBe(false)
//error message in toast should have been shown
expect(toastMethodSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
```