# Mock function of React Native component with Enzyme

Tags: react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to get going unit testing using Enzyme and Jest to mock functions of a class that extends `React.Component`, and I'm finding can mock the inherited `setState` function, but no other functions in the component.

For example, my App component has a `TextInput` that invokes `setState` on an `onChangeText` event, and a `TouchableOpacity` that invokes `submitFilter` on an `onPress` event.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = { filter: '' }
  }
  submitFilter = () => {
    if (this.state.filter.length <= 0) {
      Alert.alert('Filter is blank');
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.filterContainer}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.filterInput}
            placeholder='Filter...'
            value={this.state.filter}
            onChangeText={(text) => {this.setState({ filter: text })}}
          />
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.filterButton}
            onPress={this.submitFilter}>
            <Text style={styles.filterButtonLabel}>Go</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Using the same pattern for mocking `setState` and `submitFilter`, and the same pattern for invoking each function:

```
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('interaction', () => {
  let wrapper
  let mockFn
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = Enzyme.shallow(<App />)
    mockFn  = jest.fn()
  })
  describe('editing the filter input', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      wrapper.instance().setState = mockFn
      wrapper.find('TextInput').first().props().onChangeText('waffles');
    })
    it('should update the filter state', () => {
      expect(mockFn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    })
  })
  describe('clicking filter button', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      wrapper.instance().submitFilter = mockFn
      wrapper.find('TouchableOpacity').first().props().onPress()
    })
    it('should invoke the submitFilter callback', () => {
      expect(mockFn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    })
  })
})
```

Only the first passes, and I'm not sure what approach to use for mocking the `submitFilter` function to verify it gets invoked?

```
  interaction
    editing the filter input
      ✓ should update the filter state (3ms)
    clicking filter button
      ✕ should invoke the submitFilter callback (18ms)

  ● interaction › clicking filter button › should invoke the submitFilter callback

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)

    Expected mock function to have been called one time, but it was called zero times.

      at Object.<anonymous> (App.test.js:47:16)
      at tryCallTwo (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:45:5)
      at doResolve (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:200:13)
      at new Promise (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:66:3)
      at tryCallOne (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
      at node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After I upgraded to Enzyme 3, which required an adapter, I also ran into this problem. The way I fixed it was by looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43245040/using-jest-to-spy-on-method-call-in-componentdidmount) on StackOverflow.

According to the [migration guide](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/guides/migration-from-2-to-3.md#element-referential-identity-is-no-longer-preserved), the instance() you receive is actually a transformation of the underlying react elements. So you are not getting the actual method to mock. To fix this problem, you need to spy on the prototype.

```
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('interaction', () => {
  let wrapper
  let mockFn
  let spy

  describe('editing the filter input', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      spy = jest.spyOn(App.prototype, 'setState');
      wrapper = Enzyme.shallow(<App />);
      wrapper.find('TextInput').first().props().onChangeText('waffles');
    })
    afterEach(() => {
      spy.mockRestore();
    })
    it('should update the filter state', () => {
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    })
  })
  describe('clicking filter button', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      spy = jest.spyOn(App.prototype, 'submitFilter');
      wrapper = Enzyme.shallow(<App />);
      wrapper.find('TouchableOpacity').first().props().onPress()
    })
    afterEach(() => {
      spy.mockRestore();
    })
    it('should invoke the submitFilter callback', () => {
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this answer @worldlee78, I ended up posting the same question to the Enzyme repo in github, who pointed out as you did - to [spy on the prototype](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1432), thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome @erikse would you mind selecting my answer as the correct one if the solution works for you (so others might find it too?)