# How to test a portion of code that includes a fetch call in JavaScript

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, fetch, code-coverage

Let say I have this code (from Create React App):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('manifest.json').then(r => r.json()).then(data => {
      console.log(data);
    }).catch(e => console.log(e));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

How to test componentDidMount and get 100% code coverage?

I've used [nock](https://github.com/nock/nock) and [isomorphic-fetch](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch) but, is there a better alternative?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Jest to spy on method call in componentDidMount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43245040/using-jest-to-spy-on-method-call-in-componentdidmount)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `fetch` into your component as a prop so in your tests you can pass a mocked version of `fetch`

example Class:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount () {
      const { fetch } = this.props
      ... your fetch code ... 
      }
    }
}
```

When you are using the component, you pass in real fetch:

```
const fetch = window.fetch // or however you're importing it

const UsesFoo = () => (
 <Foo fetch={fetch} />
)
```

Now your test: (assuming jest and shallow rendering)

```
const fakeFetch = jest.fn()

it('Should mock fetch', () => {
  const res = shallow(<Foo fetch={fakeFetch} />)
})
```

Comment: I also like this "sort of Dependency Injection"... Thanks!

Comment: @MarcoAfonso no problem :) feel free to upvote if you like the solution.

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` you are referring to is a global in create-react-app based projects. Infact, afaik, they use isomorphic-fetch internally to expose this(as a poly-fill for legacy browsers). Since create-react-app comes with jest, you can use jest to mock the global before starting your tests.

Use the standard `setupTests.js` module to mock any global variable, like fetch.

You can use the `global` name space to access/mock them.

```
global.fetch = jest.fn();
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to use jest.fn().mockImplementation and create 2 window.Response, one I had to return with Promise.reject to cover the catch() case. Can you please improve your answer with my comment? thanks.