# How can I unit test body of a method in my componentDidMount() in React?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to run a unit test using Jest in React, on my `componentDidMount()` method, and only that method. my `componentDidMount()` is as follows:

```
componentDidMount() {
    //Delay to simulate welcome loading screen
    const delay = 2000;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ appLoaded: true }); //this line has no coverage, according to IDE
    }, delay);
  }
```

I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43245040/using-jest-to-spy-on-method-call-in-componentdidmount) and I got a bunch of errors. One of the big differences is that the sample given has a `componentDidMount()` method that is nothing like mine. My `componentDidMount()` has a local function in it, theirs doesn't. How can I unit test this?

also, in particular, I want to test the line that says `this.setState({ appLoaded: true });` as it's the line that's said to not be covered.

Comment: What are you using to render the component in the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you use `setTimeout`, it make sense to use fake timers: [`runTimersToTime`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks.html#advance-timers-by-time) or [advanceTimersByTime](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks.html#advance-timers-by-time) (if you're using jest v ^22.0.0). I.e.:

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

jest.useFakeTimers();

it('tracks app loaded', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<YourAwesomeComponent />);
  expect(wrapper.state('appLoaded')).toBeFalsy();
  jest.runTimersToTime(2000);
  expect(wrapper.state('appLoaded')).toBeTruthy();
});
```