# React JS Jest Unit Testing SpyOn ComponentDidMount action call, Getting Cannot spy on .. property because it is not a function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am learning to jest test react js reflux action calls from the componentDidMount() method

the jsx imports the store call like so

```
import MyStore from '~/stores/myStore'

componentDidMount() {
  MyStore.getData()
}
```

In my myStore.test.jsx code

```
import React from 'react'
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'

jest.dontMock('./myStore.jsx')

const MyStore = require('./myStore.jsx').default

describe('', () => {
   it(''), () => {
     const spy = jest.spyOn(MyStore.prototype, 'MyStore.getData')
     render.create(<MyStore/>).getInstance()
     expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
   }
}
```

I was following another similar post

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43245040/using-jest-to-spy-on-method-call-in-componentdidmount
```

But I am getting the following jest test error

```
Cannot spy the MyStore.getData() property because it is not a function
```

I have not been able to find a testing on reflux action which involves a call to the store.

Is there a fix? Is there a better way to test the calls in componentDidMount?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `getData` is a method on the `prototype`, you should use:

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(MyStore.prototype, 'getData')
```

If you want to spy on methods on the `prototype`.