# How to test if a functions is called in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

Working template of the project: https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-currying-3me1t

The only test I have set up is in `src/App.test.js` to check that a name is rendered. I am trying to setup another test that checks to see if a function is called before the buttons are generated.

In `FontAwesome.js` there is a `registerIcons()` function that registers all of the icons needed for the website. I call this function in `Buttons.js` as it is the place where I use the icons.

I want to create a test in `App.test.js` that checks to see if `registerIcons()` is called before the buttons are created in `Buttons.js`.

Comment: FYI, may be below link will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40393486/test-if-function-is-called-react-and-enzyme

Comment: Not really helpful for my case. They are testing render on click via simulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could typically do this by [manually mocking](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks) your `FontAwesome` dependency like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import Button from "./Buttons.js";
import registerIcons from './FontAwesome'

jest.mock('./FontAwesome', () => ({
  __esModule: true
  default: jest.fn()
}))


test("registers icons", () => {
  render(<Button />);

  expect(registerIcons).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

However, it seems [code sandbox does not currently support mocking](https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/513). You could try it in your own IDE though.

Comment: I am getting an error that says `TypeError: (0 , _FontAwesome.default) is not a function` and all of the stackoverflow answers for this error involved incorrectly implemented import statements. However, I think that all of my import statements are formatted correctly. Any suggestions?

Comment: I missed the `__esModule: true` from the export. I've just added it to my answer, try including that